# How to export summary statistics of a regression from R studio to Excel

Tags: r, excel, export, xlsx

I have ran a lm function and produced summary results which I wish to export onto a excel document.
Is there a specific package/code that allows me to do this? If so which is best for report presenting?

Comment: Hi lanki. This question is a bit opinion-based, and therefore off-topic for Stack Overflow. There is no "gold standard" way to display the output of `lm` as a spreadsheet. If you could give a simple example of how you would like the spreadsheet to look, you are more likely to get help here. In the meantime you might want to explore one of the packages that can output to excel, such as `openxlsx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume we have model called "mod"
mod <- lm(v1 ~ v2, data= df)

You can use "broom" function.

```
library(broom)

#create dataframes with results
res_mod <- as.data.frame(tidy(mod))
res_mod2 <- as.data.frame(glance(mod))

#then export as two csvs
write.csv(res_mod, "res_mod.csv")
write.csv(res_mod2, "res_mod2.csv")
```